# ReactJS Component's decision to use props or state to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component *Table* that needs to be rendered every time its state changes but also, **sometimes**, when new props arrive from the parent;

The *Table* component is supposed to be re-usable and handles its own state. When its width changes, I use setState(newTableWidth) to re-render the table (so far, so good).

The parent app *Project* is the one that creates the *Table* component and passes initial width.

**The problem:**
Upon changes in the parent app (or in different sub-components), I want to update the props.tableWidth and re-render *Table*. But there are other scenarios in which *Project* renders *Table* without updating the props.tableWidth.

How can *Table* know when to render itself using the props and when to render itself using the state?

Code example:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
           tableWidth: this.props.tableWidth
           columnOrder
       };
    }
   onWidthChange(newWidth){
     this.setState({tableWidth:newWidth})
   }

}

class Project extends React.Component {
 render(){
   if (this.onChangeTableWidth()){
      let width = this.calculateTableWidth();
   }
   <Table tableWidth = {width}/>
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If parent component decide to past new props to child component, the child component must obay. If there are conflicts between props and state, simply props win and the state need to reset.
I guess that one global state was solve that problem, but I understand from your question that you encapsulate some state in sub components.
According that, if parent component want to bring props that include props that maintain the current sub components, it may ask the sub component and reshape the props.

Answer (score 0):

React will automatically re-render when props or state changes, so you don't have to worry about that. You can use the [componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method to update your state with the new width received via props, just use `setState(...)` for that.

Comment: but what if there is no change in props but I want _Table_ to use props instead of state?
for example:
I render _Table_ with props: tableWidth = 100
now _Table_ changed his state to tableWidth = 200
and now _Project_ component triggered onChangeTableWidth() and need to re-render _Table_ again with tableWidth = 100
in that case props didn’t change so my tableWidth will be 200 and not 100

Comment: I would say, only let container (parent) component be responsible for changing the tableWidth, for example pass a function via props, which would act as `onChangeTableWidth(width)` handler,  and hold the width in the container, or at least always pass the width that you got via function params. This way, there is only one source of truth, which is the container component, and there is never confusion which way the width was set, as it still updates the same way. However, as someone already mentioned, you could also use some state management mechanism, I recommend you look into redux or mobx.